# Subtle differences in limit definitions

Tags: real-analysis, definition, epsilon-delta

Traditionally the limit of a sequence is defined as $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = L \Leftrightarrow$

$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N > 0)(\forall n \in \mathbf{N})(n \geq N \Rightarrow |x_n-L|<\varepsilon). \tag{1} $$

However, sometimes it seems more helpful to use the following formulation.

$$(\forall \varepsilon > 0)(\exists N > 0)(\forall n \in \mathbf{N}_{\geq N})(|x_n-L|<\varepsilon) \tag{2} $$

I’m not entirely sure that both statements are exactly equivalent, but I do have some reasons to believe so. Considering $(1)$ is immediately true $\forall n \in \mathbf{N}_{<N}$ because of the implication with a false antecedent and that for bigger $n$ the statement is true if $|x_n-a|<\varepsilon$, it seems like they are exactly equivalent.

This formulation would allow for a slightly nicer negation, but as I said, I’m not convinced enough to use $(2)$ on an exam. Could someone explain to me why there is indeed a devil in the details or why they are exactly the same?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: An intuitive idea to understand this is that you just need the elements of the sequence to be near the limit from a certain one on. A finite quantity of them won't affect the limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $P(n)$ abbreviate $|x_n-L|<\varepsilon$ . We have to show that the statements

$$\forall n \in \mathbf{N} : n \geq N \Rightarrow P(n). \tag{1} $$
and
$$\forall n \in \mathbf{N}_{\geq N} : P(n) \tag{2} $$
are equivalent.

$(1) \implies (2)$:

Let $n \in \mathbf{N}_{\geq N}$. We have to show that $$P(n)$$
is true.

Since $n \in \mathbf{N}$, we know that the implication $$n \geq N \Rightarrow P(n)$$ is true. Since the implication's premise $n \geq N$ is true for $n \in \mathbf{N}_{\geq N}$, we see that the implication's conclusion
$$P(n)$$
must be true.

$(2) \implies (1)$:

Let $n \in \mathbf{N}$. We have to show that the implication $$n \geq N \Rightarrow P(n)$$ is true.

Case 1. $n \ge N$. Then by $(2)$ the implication's conclusion
$$P(n)$$
is true. Thus the implication is true for this $n$.

Case 2. $n < N$. Then the implication's premise
$$n \ge N$$
is false. Thus the implication is true for this $n$.

Comment: This is exactly the sort of rigour I was hoping for. Thank you for taking the time to formulate it so clearly.

Comment: @Jan It's worth noting this is a general thing about how quantifiers and subsets work. $\forall x\in S, P(x)$ *means* $\forall x, (x\in S\implies P(x))$. And if $S$ is a subset of $T$ (so that $x\in S\implies x\in T$), then $x\in T\implies (x\in S\implies P(x))$ is logically equivalent to $x\in S\implies P(x)$.